# Identifying relationship in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
    CUSTOMER_ID   NUMBER(3),
    NAME VARCHAR2(10),
    ADDR VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE ISSUE_CARD 
(
    CUSTOMER_ID  NUMBER(3),
    CARD_ID NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE TABLE CARD 
(
    CARD_ID NUMBER(3)
);
```

I'd like to set the relationship between the `Customer` and `ISSUE_CARD` tables as follows:

- customer table's minimum cardinality is 0
- customer table's maximum cardinality is 1

The relationship means that a customer can be inserted into the table "without" card. Also a customer can be inserted into the table "with" a card.

So I have to add some constraint to the `Customer` table, but I don't know how to do that, since the value must be inserted into the table if I add foreign key into `Customer` table

I think this case is not adjustable to non-identifying relationship, but I think this case is considered as an identifying relationship.

Thank you.

Comment: `value must be inserted into the table if I add the foreign key into Customer table` -> This is not true. You can keep the FK column value to NULL also.

Answer (score 0):

If a customer can only have either 0 or 1 cards then you don't need the ISSUE_CARD table. Just add a CARD_ID column to the CUSTOMER table.

Bridge tables like ISSUE_CARD are only required to support many-to-many relationships.